# How to configure PowerApp Portal default SendInvitation flow to send emails from custom mailbox?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-portal

I have created a powerapp portal and require to implement invitation based user registration,
Some documents and video tutorials mention we can use the default SendInvitaion flow to send emails to contacts.
But when I click on send invitation flow, emails does not generate for contacts, Does anyone know how to debug this issue? or do I need to configure default flow somewhere else?

[image]

Invitation table shows status as "Sent".

[image]

Portal management shows status as "Sent"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, below are the steps that resolve it.

1. Go to my solution.
2. Click settings (Gear icon right upper)
3. Go to Power Platform Admin Center
4. Select the appropriate environment
5. Settings ==> Email ==> EmailBoxes
6. Select email account and click on "Test & Enable Mailbox"
7. Then "Approve Email"